# Win32 Make menu non-global but accessible by all childprocs

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm making a paint program where I have MDI and multiple dialogs that need to access menu items.

Right now, I stick the menu in global so everything can see it. However, I'd like to use

```
typedef struct datastruct
{
    DWORD currentTool;
    POINT start, end;
    DWORD lastShape;
    HINSTANCE hInst;
    HMENU     hMenuInit, hMenuHello;
    HMENU     hMenuInitWindow, hMenuHelloWindow;
}
DATA, *PDATA;
```

This struct, along with `PDATA pdata = 0, pglobaldata=0;`

To access the following items:

```
HINSTANCE hInst;
HMENU     hMenuInit, hMenu;
HMENU     hMenuInitWindow, hMenuWindow;
```

For example, when I need to access hMenuInit in a MDI child window, I would do this: `pglobaldata->hMenuInit` and I'd be able to access the same one WinMain is using: `hMenuInit  = LoadMenu (hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU));`

How can I accomplish this?

Having issues pasting all the code here. I've put it on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/z9tKSwhG

Comment: Are there any classes in your program? Seems like those variables, or that struct, should be members of the main window class.

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I include the struct in the header, I've updated my post to include the rest of my code.

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: Don't you just want to declare a global variable of type `DATA`? Or do you have multiple main windows?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Within each proc, I want to use the local variable pdata, but I want to use GetWindowLongPtr and SetWindowLongPtr to access a shared copy of the data across procs/windows to keep things like menu items synchronized

Comment: So you want to know how to define instance data for the window?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I think that's what it would be called? Not too sure. I was asked to not use globals, but I'm struggling quite a bit with that. Not very experienced with the winapi

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to associate some instance specific data with the window. You do that by specifying the size of the extra data in the `cbWndExtra` member of `WNDCLASSEX` when you register the window class. And then access that extra data call `GetWindowLongPtr` and `SetWindowLongPtr` passing `0`  for `nIndex`. That index identifies the slow where your instance data is stored.

Comment: Thanks David, that's what I've been trying to do, but to no avail.
My code here: http://pastebin.com/L18E4vEq works fine until I press New in the File menu, which is supposed to create an MDI child window. I know this should work because I got pretty much everything working before trying to remove globals.

Comment: It works fine. Try in a simple test project. I can't look at the immense pastebin. If you want to show code, make an sscce.